# Date won't change after using DATEADD() function in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

I have a date stored in a string (`@cnp=1051597991234`) the date being `051597` representing `5/15/1997`. I am using the following code to set a date variable with the needed value, in the end to compute the current age.

I used the debugger but somehow it ends up being not set and the diff also returning null.

If someone could help I would be very grateful

```
declare @cnp varchar(30) = 1051597991234;
declare @age int;
declare @dateBorn date = CAST('1900-01-01' AS DATETIME);

declare @dayBorn int;
declare @monthBorn int;
declare @yearBorn int;

set @dayBorn = cast(substring(@cnp, 2, 2) as int) - 1;
set @monthBorn = cast(substring(@cnp, 4, 2) as int) - 1;
set @yearBorn = cast(substring(@cnp, 6, 2) as int);

set @dateBorn = dateadd(yyyy, @yearBorn, @dateBorn);
set @dateBorn = dateadd(mm, @monthBorn, @dateBorn);
set @dateBorn = dateadd(dd, @dayBorn, @dateBorn);

set @age = datediff(year, getdate(), @dateBorn);
```

Comment: You know you're getting a syntax error for your first line, right?  Fix that?  *(missing the datatype : `NVARCHAR(32)` or similar?)*

Comment: i didnt post the whole procedure, @cnp is varchar(13)

Comment: then you're doing something else wrong and you should include the whole procedure that's failing : http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=0dc0690384ddd81005001d7c09462c01

Comment: i included the part that is failing, i checked with the debugger and everything sets fine until this point

Comment: See my link to dbfiddle in the comments above : If you fix the first line, everything else works.  *(After your edit, the script you have provided executes just fine, though with a negative age.  The issue you are facing is not in that code snippet.)*

Comment: yeah sorry, sql server doesn't make any sense but, i found  the mistake after the code fixed itself(???). Its in the datediff function the parameter are in the wrong order its supposed to be datediff(year,@dateBorn, getdate() ); even tho you compute the difference between getdate and dateborn and not dateborn and getdate. thanks for the help

Comment: The code did not fix itself.  Don't be insane.  Something else changed.  Deterministic results don't change without the input, the code, or the environment changing.

Comment: Side note: this is a terrible way to store a date.  First, not only is it not one of the many `Date`-related types in SQL Server (most of which will be _smaller_ in size), it's also not SARGable, meaning searching on this as a date is going to be painful, and somewhat useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's declaration problem. Just change this

```
declare @cnp = 1051597991234
```

with this

```
declare @cnp nvarchar(20) ='1051597991234'
```

and also change  the sequence for as from date will be date of birth

```
set @age =datediff(year,@dateBorn,getdate());
```

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest using the `DATEFROMPARTS` function?

So:

```
DECLARE @dateBorn DATE = 
    DATEFROMPARTS(
        CAST('19' + SUBSTRING(@cnp,6,2) AS INT)
        ,CAST(SUBSTRING(@cnp,2,2) AS INT)
        ,CAST(SUBSTRING(@cnp,4,2) AS INT)
        );

DECLARE @age INT = 
    DATEDIFF(YEAR, GETDATE(), @dateBorn);
```

Please note that the birthdate strings you have are not Y2K safe, which is why I've put a constant in to assume that they were in the 20th century.

Also note that your dates are in American format, with the month first, day second, and year third.

Comment: thanks but i am getting this error "Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid."